# how to add flutter_downloader integration for IOS in the info.plist file

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, mobile, download

how to add flutter_downloader integration for IOS in the info.plist file

I want to add flutter_downloader integration for IOS, I follow here
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader. for the Optional configuration section I am confused enough to place it on the side. The description says in the info.plist file and the following is my code

[image: Info.plist file]

Comment: Add optional configuration at `<1>` place

Answer (score 2):

It should be at `<1>` place.
Or Inside `<dict>` tag which is just a descendent of `<plist>` tag.

you can verify it from the example code:
https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_downloader/blob/master/example/ios/Runner/Info.plist

Answer (score -1):

Visit https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader

in this link following iOS integration step by step configuration